# SharePoint Online Picture Sync

Tags: office365, user-profile, sharepoint-online

I'm having problems displaying all users pictures in SharePoint online.
All user profiles properties are set the same:

```
Picture Exchange Sync State = 1
Picture Placeholder State = 1
```

If I look in https://-my.sharepoint.com/User%20Photos
All names of pictures are there, but some are the generic grey picture.

I'm having trouble deciding where the error lies. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

At first , you could check whether the users have their photos in Exchange online .If there’s no user photo in Exchange online it will not appear in SharePoint online too.If this issue affects only a few users , you could try below steps as a workaround :

1) As an Admin, browse to Tenant Admin | User profiles.

2) In the People section, click 'Manage user profiles'

3) Search for a broken user.

4) Edit the profile. Set 'Picture Exchange Sync State' to 0 and save the profile.

5) Edit the profile again. This time, on the 'Picture' property, click 'Remove' to remove the picture from SharePoint.

6) Edit the profile a third time. This time, set 'Picture Exchange Sync State' back to 1.

7) Have the user browse to their My Site (It may take some time for the cache to clear and this to reset).

For more details, please also check [this thread](https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/158519) and [this thread](https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/349534) .