# Profile Picture fails to sync in Teams and Sharepoint Online

Tags: active-directory, office365, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

bit of a strange one so I hope someone has some ideas.

We have updated several hundred user's profile photos through the Graph API and have also pushed the same photo to Active Directory (thumbnailPhoto). The photos for users are present on Azure AD, and also visible in 365 Admin Centre.

We are having issues getting these pictures to also replicate into teams; users with a new photos are still showing the generic profile photo. This is true for both the browser and app versions of teams. Sharepoint Online is also inconsistent in showing the updated photo. We assumed this would refresh over time but 24 hours in most users are still showing new photos present in 365/Azure but not in Teams or SPO.

Clearing cache in teams was also ineffective, is there another step we're missing here, or can push the changes through?

*also posted to Teams Tech community but thought it would be worth a try here.

Comment: Could you please confirm which API permissions you have given? Meanwhile we are also trying this at our end, waiting for the update to sync.

Comment: Could you please let us know if the below workaround resolved your issue?

Comment: In regards to API permissions, where would I find those? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-update?msclkid=2f706b5ab67a11ec96a74dfead9f8e9f&view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions

Comment: Our app has user.WriteAll and Contacts.ReadWrite Permissions, and photos are uploading to 365 and graph fine. The steps that were recommended for SPO haven't yet synched across. Which is strange because all the photos are also present on Exchange Online.

Answer (score 3):

**To resolve profile picture sync issue in Teams, please check the below suggestions:**

- Completely exit from Microsoft Teams by selecting quit or use Task Manager to stop the process.
- Please check whether you have cleared the cache in all the folders mentioned below.
- Open file explorer, search %appdata%\Microsoft\teams.
- Make sure to delete all the files with below format in those folders.

  - ***Application cache*** ->* %appdata%\Microsoft\teams\application cache\cache
  - ***Blob_storage*** -> * %appdata%\Microsoft\teams\blob_storage
  - ***Cache*** -> * %appdata%\Microsoft\teams\Cache
  - ***databases*** -> * %appdata%\Microsoft\teams\databases
  - ***GPUCache*** -> * %appdata%\Microsoft\teams\GPUcache
  - ***IndexedDB*** -> * %appdata%\Microsoft\teams\IndexedDB
  - ***Local Storage*** -> * %appdata%\Microsoft\teams\Local Storage
  - ***tmp*** -> * %appdata%\Microsoft\teams\tmp

After clearing all the cache, restart Microsoft Teams in your local desktop.

**To resolve profile picture sync issue in SharePoint, please check the below suggestions:**

- Please check whether the users have their pictures in ***Exchange Online***.
- If no picture exists in Exchange Online, it won't appear in SharePoint Online too.
- To upload the pictures to Exchange Online, make use of [Set-UserPhoto](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj218694(v=exchg.160).aspx) PowerShell cmdlet.
- To sync profile picture properly, please try below steps as a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36693285/sharepoint-online-picture-sync?rq=1):

  - Make sure you have **Admin** role.
  - Go to Tenant Admin -> User Profiles -> Under People Section -> Manage User Profiles
  - Select users -> Edit Profile -> Set `Picture Exchange Sync State` to **0** and save the profile.
  - Edit the profile again, select 'Picture' property and choose 'Remove' that removes the picture from SharePoint.
  - Edit the profile once more by setting  `Picture Exchange Sync State` to **1**
  - Please note that it would take a while to clear the cache and to be reset.

Please find these ***references*** if they are helpful: [Ref1](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2295978-profile-picture-not-updated-in-teams), [Ref2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/information-about-profile-picture-synchronization-in-microsoft-365-20594d76-d054-4af4-a660-401133e3d48a)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @SrideviMachavarapu-MT, have managed to do steps up until 'Edit profile again and remove'. We don't have that option either due to our tenant settings or because the user has the generic grey silhouette. They did have a picture file in the Profile Picutres folder which I have now deleted and am waiting for a sync or a cache refresh. 

The larger issues is we'll be looking to do this for up to 2000 staff, and don't want to edit the picture exchange sync state value individually. Is there better solution for batch updates?